# Error 400 when i try to upload picture on cloudinary

Tags: plugins, strapi

I am using cloudinary plugin on Strapi.
Everything was great until i did a yarn build command. I have the following issue : when i try to upload an image, i have those errors :

- In my strapi Media library : Files are empty
- In my console :

"{"files":{},"fileInfo":"{"name":"testConcepttwo.jpg","caption":"testConcepttwo.jpg","alternativeText":"testConcepttwo.jpg","folder":null}"}"
env
:
{FormData: ƒ, Blob: ƒ}
{status: 400, name: 'ApplicationError', message: 'Files are empty', details: {…}}

I am struggling with that since this morning and i still did not found a solution..

Is anyone could please help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and how I fixed it was by removing the "axios" package.

```
yarn remove axios

yarn build
```